# WCF Proxy not being generated properly

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a WCF Service that needs to return a file from a database.  To that end, I have created two MessageContract classes, one for input and one for output.  The code is as follows:

```
[MessageContract]
public class AttachmentFile
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public Int32 AttachmentID;

    [MessageHeader]
    public String FileName;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream Data;

    public AttachmentFile(Attachment att)
    {
        AttachmentID = (Int32)att.AttachmentID;
        FileName = att.FileName;
        Data = new MemoryStream(att.FileBytes);
    }
}

[MessageContract]
public class AttachmentFileID
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Int32 AttachmentID;
}

public AttachmentFile GetAttachmentFile(AttachmentFileID AttachmentID)
{
}
```

The generated WSDL looks correct:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetAttachmentFile">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IAttachments/GetAttachmentFile" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input name="AttachmentFileID">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="AttachmentFile">
        <soap12:header message="i0:AttachmentFile_Headers" part="AttachmentID" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="i0:AttachmentFile_Headers" part="FileName" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

However, when I run `svcutil.exe http://localhost:8002/IAttachments?wsdl`, the generated code comes out as:

```
public string GetAttachmentFile(ref int AttachmentID, out System.IO.Stream Data)
{
    AttachmentFileID inValue = new AttachmentFileID();
    inValue.AttachmentID = AttachmentID;
    AttachmentFile retVal = ((IAttachments)(this)).GetAttachmentFile(inValue);
    AttachmentID = retVal.AttachmentID;
    Data = retVal.Data;
    return retVal.FileName;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't seem to find what it is.  Does anyone have any clues to what could be causing this?

Comment: What if you call `svcutil` with a `/wrapped` parameter? This will prevent "unwrapping" the parameters (as seems to happen in your case...). Also - try the `/messageContract` switch on svcutil to tell it you're using a message contract - helps at times...

Comment: Nothing is wrong - the contract is the same. You should be able to call the service with that client and it should work out just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  The /messagecontract switch did the trick.  As soon as I figure out how, I'll accept your answer.

carlosfigueira:  While I know that it's technically correct and will work, it's now how the original call was written and worse, it's not intuitive.  My boss would never accept a call like that in our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further examination of the code, the `/messageContract` switch fixed one of the calls only to screw up another one.  However, using the /importXmlTypes switch fixed everything.